# Which do you appreciate the most

Tags: phrase-usage

Do "Which do you appreciate the most" and "Which do you appreciate most" share the same meaning and both are correct?

> **Which do you appreciate the most**, politicians or scientists?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/most-the-most-mostly

Comment: They both sound as good to me.

Comment: Yes. Using *the* or not does not change the point of the question. However, it is a false dichotomy, as often scientists are politicians. :)

Comment: On a side issue, if you were comparing just two groups (scientists and politicians) you would ask: **Which do you appreciate more?**